# How can I safely give my Google Cloud application credentials to another person?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I am working on a small project with Java in IntelliJ that uses the Google Cloud Translation API. For managing the dependencies, I use maven. My goal is to create an executable jar.

In my current situation, I have downloaded the .json file that stores my private key and set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS that points to the location of the .json file either in my IDE via "Run configurations" or with a prompt in the command line before starting the executable jar.

But here is the problem: It works fine on my own computer, but how am I supposed to let another person like my supervisor use my application on their computer? I surely do not want to upload my credentials to a github repo, so my idea was to send him the .json file and let him know that he has to set the environment variable by himself.

I would appreciate any help :)

EDIT: I try to specify my problem - What is the intended way from Google so that other people can run my app? Am I supposed to share my service account's credentials, or can I somehow include them safely into the jar? Because without setting the environment variable, the jar won't start

Comment: can you generate another api key for him?

Comment: I could generate another key but the problem would stay the same because they belong to the same service account. 
I was also thinking of adding a small instruction in the readme.
I guess my supervisor was hoping that I could somehow include the key safely in the jar or create a key for the sole purpose of testing. I am just confused about the way how to deal with those credentials.

Comment: For your use case, is using a service account the correct authorization mechanism? Your question does not include details on the service or how it is used or what it interfaces with. If users are using your application OAuth **user** credentials are appropriate. If this is a backend service that should use a service account, then create a new service account key for your manager.

Comment: I am not even sure about that, I chose the authorization method based on [this setup guide](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/setup-basic). It's just a small research project. The idea is that the application user can translate text locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Authentication Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/best-practices-applications), if you are "developing locally to test or learn", users could login using the [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) tool with the [application-default](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) login. You can put these commands in a bash script or readme.md for convenience:

```
gcloud auth revoke
gcloud auth application-default revoke
gcloud auth application-default login /
   --billing-project=<BILLING_PROJECT> /
   --scopes=openid,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-translation.readonly
```

##### Notes

- If you're running Translate API v3 you will need to provide its scope in the command, but if you're running v2, you may not need them at all.
- To be safe, you can omit the billing project name from the command in git and have the users enter this themselves.
- The current user must be logged out first to ensure the correct credentials are used.
- You may also need to grant the appropriate [Cloud Translation IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-translation-roles) to the user.

##### What happens when you run it?

- Running this CLI command will open a browser window and request that the user login to Google Cloud.
- A prompt may also appear to install [Cloud Resource Manager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager). This is used to manage the hierarchy of GCP resources (projects, roles, services, etc.) and is totally free.
- Once the user has logged in, a file called `application_default_credentials.json` is created in the local Google Cloud SDK configuration folder.

##### What about the service private key?

If you use this `gcloud` login method, you do not need the service's private key or the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. However, if that variable is present, the credentials file it points to will be used instead. This logic is part of the [Application Default Credentials](https://google.aip.dev/auth/4110) workflow used by most modern Google Cloud clients.

Comment: @rappingbarley After understanding your use case a bit better and digging a bit deeper, I found this recommendation from Google (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/best-practices-applications#local_development_and_testing_with_the)) that doesn't require sharing the credentials json file. I haven't tested this though, so if you do, please let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I tried your approach by installing the Google Cloud SDK and using this command. I got an invalid_scope error  because of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-translation.readonly. BTW, I am using the Basic Version of Google Cloud Translation (v2), and I couldn't find any scope for it. I then adapted the command a bit by deleting the translation scope (and adding a scope for Cloud Vision), tried again, the browser popped up, I signed in with my account and a json was created. Then I was asked to install the Cloud Resource Manager - I did, it's free right?

Comment: After that I got a warning: com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider warnAboutProblematicCredentials
WARNUNG: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.
Can someone explain? But it worked! Thank you so much, you're a life saver!

Comment: I have one more question: If I would publish my code on github with this command in the readme file including the name of my billing project, wouldn't everyone be able to create users? Should I leave the billing project blank like in your example and let my supervisor know about the billing ID separately?

Comment: @rappingbarley Yes, the [Resource Manager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager) is free. It's used to organize the hierarchy of GCP resources (projects, roles, services, etc.) To get rid of the warning, try running `gcloud auth revoke` to log out first and see if that helps. If not, then the warning may be expected. Remember, the service account is the correct way to do this, but for test/dev/R&D, Google approves user sign-ins. Re: sharing billing project name, when in doubt, play it safe. Leave it blank in git and have your supervisor fill it in. Your discretion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Json files are normally associated with service accounts, not users (ie real people), so I assume you are not talking about your private key, but the private key of a service account.

The simplest option is to indeed give json file with the key to the other person and instruct them to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable.

Note that this will give anyone with that json file access to whatever that service account has permissions for. **I would highly recommend to restrict these permissions to the minimum** (probably just the translation API and nothing more).

Comment: You are right, the json file belongs to the service account. I will see what I can do regarding possible restrictions.

Comment: Alternatively one could use Workload Identity (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#:~:text=A%20credential%20configuration%20file%20for%20workload%20identity%20federation) and set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to a config.json instead of a key.json file.

Answer (score 1):

### Tl;DR

Never share your credentials: neither user account credentials keys nor service account credentials keys.

### Alternatives

Since you haven't shared much context about your application type and its deployment plan, I would go with general alternatives to sharing your user (and service) sensitive information.

1. Instruct the final user to use Application Default Credentials (ADC) as a recommended way for local / test environments where you are prototyping a solution. The user should have a GCP project set with billing enabled and they will have to simply authenticate using below command then they will be able to run your application without any further modifications locally:

   `gcloud auth application-default login`
2. Deploy your application to one of Google Cloud Compute family services. I would recommend *Cloud Run* as this may be the one with little or no setup hassle if you are able to build a container (which is presumably true given a *Java* application). Once you application deployed to a secure environment with its service-account properly configured, you can then share the application facing interface with other users.
   Note meanwhile that this approach is acceptable if you are only intending to have others access your application as final users would.